# How can I get a useful stack trace from a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's imagine that I have a file called myfile.js. Inside of myfile.js I have the following code:

```
$(document).on("my_custom_event", function(e)
{
    my_custom_function(e);
    alert(undefined[1]); // This is only to trigger an exception, it's not normally used
});
```

Now, I have my index.html file that will include that JS file and, upon my_custom_event being fired, trigger that exception.

I'm trying to have a catch-all for error handling so I can display an appropriate error message and stack trace to the user so they can report the issue, so I tried using window.onerror, like so:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, column, error) {
    var error = {
        "_type": "EXCEPT",
        "_msg": "A critical error has occurred.<br/>" + msg + ((error !== undefined) ? "<br/>" + error.stack : "<br/>URL: " + url + ", line " + line)
    };
    $.event.trigger({type:"message_event", object:error});
};
```

Assume that message_event is handled elsewhere in another function, and displays the message to the user. jQuery is also included in the index.html file, so everything is actually working for that. Neither of the potential outputs from the above window.onerror function gives anything useful, as they just go through the jQuery stack trace and have no mention of myfile.js whatsoever.

Is there some way that I can actually report that the issue lies in myfile.js? It doesn't have to be through window.onerror, but a try/catch in myfile.js isn't really an option since I have hundreds of these kinds of functions (albeit with proper code that would only throw exceptions when a real error happens) and adding a try/catch to them all would take weeks.

I should mention that I have also tried using stacktrace.js (http://stacktracejs.com/) but it doesn't provide anything useful either.

Comment: Does this give you anything useful? `console.log(error.stack)` testing in http://jsfiddle.net/f2DLt/ with chrome, it gives a full stack of the error, which i can use to find the exact line where it failed (which in this case is an inline script so it gives me the view source line number 24) Edit: Ah, i see you're using it. I wonder why it isn't giving you anything useful.